# php "All authentication must be done over SSL" using SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, ssl

I'm communicating with a SOAP webservice using PHP and I'm having trouble.

```
// Create SOAP client object
$objClient = new SoapClient("https://panopto_host/Panopto/PublicAPI/4.0/Auth.svc?wsdl", array('trace' => true));

// These parameters satisfy this specific remote call.
$loginParams = array('userKey' => 'cmjw', 'password' => 'bleh');

$objLogin =  $objClient->LogOnWithPassword($loginParams);
```

The error I get is  "**All authentication must be done over SSL**". I don't know if this a server application error message, or a standard SOAP error, but the wierd thing is that I created very simple program in .Net, creating a service reference to generate a proxy class, and it works fine.

What am I missing with PHP to make the method call use SSL?

Thanks for any advice.
Corey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service URL in the WSDL is an HTTP URL then even though the WSDL is downloaded over HTTPS the request might be made over HTTP.

Comment: https://dlri.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/PublicAPI/4.0/Auth.svc?wsdl  [link](https://dlri.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/PublicAPI/4.0/Auth.svc?wsdl)

Comment: I think that the element `operation` `LogOnWithPassword` is pointing at the http URL `http://tempuri.org/IAuth/LogOnWithPassword` not an https one

Comment: Good point.  Following that line of thought, I looked at the service soap:address location and it had http, which can't be right.  When I downloaded the WSDL, changed it to https, referenced it, it now appears to work.  Thanks for the point in the right direction.  .Net worked because it has the https in the service reference.